# UART signal quality and ESD protection

Tags: microcontroller, uart, esd

Our circuit has its UART port connecting with a central control board. And I am thinking on the ESD issues.

1. The UART runs at 56700 baud rate.
2. The UART communication is between two stm32f407 chips. [STM32F407](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577/LN11/PF252149?sc=internet/mcu/product/252149.jsp)

Since the speed we need is rather low, my initial thought is to add a simple RC filter in front of the UART TX/RX pins, which will absorb spikes. Now the problem becomes what shall be the values of the RC filter. The following diagram shows the values that I am using:

[image: RC filter]

Before trying to find out if they are sufficient for ESD protection. My question is, will it influence the functionality of the UART? I did a simple simulation using the same diagram above. The pulse train used in this simulation has similar speed comparing with UART baud rate, which is 100kHz. It can be seen that the signals have been distorted. 
My questions are:

1. How could know if the signal distortion will influence UART communication or not?
2. What are the specs to tell this from?
3. Shall I also add a schottkey diode at the 3.3V side to protect the power rail?

[image: RC filter]

Comment: Sorry, I did not really get what you refer to. Are you suggesting using diodes? If so, I prefer rc circuits in this case because we do not need high speed. I think rc filters are sufficient.

Comment: Bad idea.  An actual ESD would find your filter laughable.  You might consider one for EMI, but it will not be effective for ESD.

Comment: You've shot down every person telling you to use real ESD protection parts (yes, which are diodes). The junction capacitance of them is laughably small and they are sold to work on interfaces as fast as HDMI -- I assure you they will not be a problem on a simple 115200 UART. A RC filter is not the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Why exactly do you come in here asking if this will work and how, and then when everybody tells you it will not and to use ESD protection diodes such as TVS (which can be as cheap as caps) you keep insisting "no it can definitely done by what I am asking you guys about". If you're so sure, why are you asking a question? And for the record: Yes you do need actual ESD protection, even if it's only 1kHz, and no an RC filter will not work, if anything it's more likely to make the problems worse.

Comment: Why would RC filters not work? Could I know the reasons? The reason for me to ask here is to find a solution in a specific way. I do know diodes will work. That is simply not my question.

Comment: There are two reasons for me to ask this. Firstly, we have almost all kinds of resistors and capacitors in 0402 packages, but do not have TVS diodes or ESD suppressors. Secondly, I am looking for alternatives on ESD protection when signals running at low speed. I would love to know more about the working principles of the IO pin: what kind of rising/falling times are acceptable? How would internal diodes help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can you use ESD diodes on UART signals. I had done it in past reaching up to 115200.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did not want to use TVS because in this application speed is not an issue. I think rc filters shall be sufficient.

Comment: I recommended this for future compatibility i.e you don't have to re-calculate RC value every time :->>

Answer (score 1):

**Are ESD diodes ok:**

ESD diodes can be used on high speed digital, all designs like cellular SIM card interfaces running SPI require ESD diodes. Your signal will only experience the junction capacitance, which is on the order of 10s of pF vs an RC filter where you have 10nF.

As mentioned, capacitance on your digital line is what causes distortions, so as long as you have low capacitance with respect to your frequency you should be fine.

I'm not sure what you mean about adding a schottkey diode though...

**How to determine how much signal integrity is needed:**

Look at the receiving device datasheet and see what it considers a logic 1 and 0, then compare that to your signal and see what the difference is between when you say it should be a 1 vs when it really is seen as a logic 1 by your device.

Then depending on your application, decide if the difference is acceptable.

I personally would shoot for a rise time and fall time of no more then 10% the total on/off time \$(T_p/2)\$. i.e. if I am operating at 1kHz, my \$T_p=500us\$, so I would shoot for a rise time (10% to 90%) to be < 50us. That is just personal oppinion, I'm sure others will have different ideas. It really comes down to what I said above, what can your application *handle* and what does it *need*.

Comment: Instead of diodes, I prefer rc circuits in this case because we do not need high speed. I think rc filters are sufficient.

Comment: Rc filters shall be able to absorb the esd charges. My question here is to figure out "how much distortion is acceptable". Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to protect from? Something like 8k ESD? are you sure your RC filter is sufficient?

Comment: Not quite sure, will figure out that surely. Yes contact 8k and 15k in air.

Comment: May I also ask why you have a 10nF cap (C1) where it is? All that will do is cause a short circuit with every transition on your PWM driver or whatever is driving the signal.

Comment: The reason I ask is because although you do not see it in the simulation, in real life there is inductance in your supply line, that paired with the short circuit of the C1 capacitor, you will get ringing on the rising edge of your PWM signal. Depending on the physical implementation (if it is not all on a PCB) it could be significant ringing.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. For C1, I was trying to build a pi filter. I do understand that the caps and resistors cause the distortion. If I am correct, I thought the ESD will be absorbed in the same way. People commented that RC filters cannot filter the ESDs, do you know why is that?

Comment: First off, a PI filter will not get you much more then a RC filter, I would stick with an RC if you want to go this route since it is not a direct short circuit and will reduce ringing on the line. You could test it creating a PCB with a PI and populating C1 on a few. Second an RC filter may absorb the ESD, but the super high voltage and associated ripple from it may not be absorbed by the capacitor quick enough. I am no expert here but some issues could be breakdown of the capacitor due to a huge voltage, or if the C has to high ESL... All I can say is in industry i have never seen it.

Comment: Asmyldof said it well, ESD diodes are designed for this, a capacitor is not. with super high voltage, odd things happen. Also ESD diodes are cheep... Do you have a reason not to use them?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. One reason is we have almost all resistors and caps in 0402. The other is I wish to dig into the working principles of IO pins, to see what may work what may not. The third reason is I got advices from some ESD specialist doing in this way for low speed signals. They also suggested using ESD suppressors at the same time. But I am wondering if it could be done without those. You have a good point that the caps and resistors may get broken under high voltages, thanks!

Comment: In the final design I may choose using diodes or even chips for smaller space. Here I just want to find out the reasons.

Comment: Also note that if you plan to do the RC circuit, I would not use a 402 package cap, 8kV would most likely arc the capacitor before it absorbed the charge... If your trying to avoid a diode due to the size, there is a reason it is big... Again I am not an ESD expert, someone else here may be able to give you a more accurate answer on why RC filters are not often used. If an 'expert' told you it was ok, then maybe trust him over me.

Comment: By arc the capacitor, do you mean the esd will jump over the cap or destroy the cap? For the specialist, they also suggest to use RC filters with ESD suppressor devices, which have much lower leakage current with shorter opening time.

Comment: Define RC with ESD device? This I have seen, the RC filter can help slow down the ESD discharge and give the ESD device more time to respond if that is what you mean. And yes, jump the capacitor I mean arc over. in open air 8kV will jump at-least 2mm.